# How to get a Bootstrap Carousel to slide images in steps

Tags: css, image, slideshow, carousel

I'll try to make this as clear as I can;

I'm trying to make a slideshow on my website with, say, 4 images. I'd like them to display two at a time, and for the carousel to rotate through the list.

Example:

< 1 [2 3] 4 >

< [1 2] 3 4 >

< 1 2 [3 4] >

The square brackets show where the slideshow's viewbox is.

Is this possible at all? Perhaps I need something other than Carousel?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you maybe show what you have already tried so far. We need some code to be able to help you.

Comment: You're probably right, isherwood, I'll give it a look.